# How can I display the page category name, not just the post category name?

Tags: php, wordpress

This code displays the post category name, but I need to display the page category name as well. What do I need to change in this code? I am using "Create And Assign Categories For Pages" plugin.

```
<?php if ('post' == get_post_type($post->ID) && rehub_option('exclude_cat_meta') != 1) :?>
  <?php $category = get_the_category($post->ID);  ?>
  <?php if ($category) {
     if ( class_exists( 'WPSEO_Primary_Term' ) ) {
          $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', $post->ID );
          $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
          if (!is_numeric($wpseo_primary_term )) {
              $first_cat = $category[0]->term_id;
          }else{
              $first_cat = $wpseo_primary_term; 
          }
      }else{
         $first_cat = $category[0]->term_id; 
      }
      meta_small( false, $first_cat, false, false );
 }    endif; ?>
```